# Invalid qualifier Error Message in vba code

Tags: vba, excel

This code is designed to detect the columns of start and finish of a shape which is used and displayed onto the caption of the shape itself. The following code is the problematic code:

```
Sub Take_Baseline()
Dim forcast_weeksStart() As String
Dim forcast_weeksEnd() As String
Dim forcastDate As String
Dim shp As Shape
Dim split_text() As String




'cycle through all the shapes in the worsheet and enter the forcast date for all the projects into their respective boxes



For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes

          'initialize forcast date by parsing
    forcast_weeksStart = Split(shp.TopLeftCell.Column.Text, " ")
    forcast_weeksEnd = Split(shp.BottomRightCell.Column.Text, " ")
    forcastDate = forcast_weeksStart(1) & "-" & forcast_weeksEnd(1)


        temp = shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Caption
        If InStr(temp, "/-/") > 0 & InStr(temp, "In Prog") Then
            split_text = Split(shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption, " ")
            For i = 0 To (i = 3)
                            shp.TextFrame.Characters.Caption = split_text(i) & vbNewLine
                        Next i
                        ActiveSheet.Shapes(Sheet4.Range("B1")).TextFrame.Characters.Caption = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Sheet4.Range("B1")).TextFrame.Characters.Caption & vbNewLine & ActiveSheet.Cells(4, AShape.TopLeftCell.Column).Text & " - " & ActiveSheet.Cells(4, AShape.BottomRightCell.Column).Text & vbNewLine & "dates: " & forcast_weeksStart(1) & " - " & forcast_weeksEnd(1) & "/" & forcast_weeksStart(1) & " - " & forcast_weeksEnd(1) & "/" & "/" & "actualDate"
       ' ElseIf InStr(temp, "/-/") > 0 & InStr(temp, "In Prog") = 0 Then
             'split_text = Split(shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Caption, " ")
           ' For i = 0 To (i = 2)
                           ' shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = split_text(i) & vbNewLine
                       ' Next i
                        'ActiveSheet.Shapes(Sheet4.Range("B1")).TextFrame.Characters.Caption = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Sheet4.Range("B1")).TextFrame.Characters.Caption & vbNewLine & "In Prog" & vbNewLine & ActiveSheet.Cells(4, AShape.TopLeftCell.Column).Text & " - " & ActiveSheet.Cells(4, AShape.BottomRightCell.Column).Text & vbNewLine & "dates: " & forcast_weeksStart(1) & " - " & forcast_weeksEnd(1) & "/" & forcast_weeksStart(1) & " - " & forcast_weeksEnd(1) & "/" & "actualDate"
        End If
    Next shp


    'For testing purposes

    Sheet4.Range("A20").Value = forcast_weeksStart(1)
    Sheet4.Range("A21").Value = forcast_weeksEnd(1) End Sub
```

The error is an

> "invalid qualifier"

message which occurs on line

```
forcast_weeksStart = Split(shp.TopLeftCell.Column.Text, " ")
```

Right on the "column" word. I don't get why this is happening since the actual drop down menu has the column operation which i can select. I have tried everything from changing it to the OLEformat.Object.Caption etc etc. But nothing has worked. I am still relatively new to vba so any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: it is also important to note that I looked up the error message and it indicates that the operation is not within "current scope" not sure how this relates to my issue. If anyone can shed light with a solution would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `shp.TopLeftCell.Column` returns a Long.  Longs do not have a `.Text` child.

Comment: I've never heard of "TopLeftCell", are you sure that's not pseudocode/placeholder?

Comment: `TopLeftCell` returns `range` object and `column` returns the column number of that range. This `TopLeftCell.Column.Text` no sense.